# Displaying a MKMapView underneath html elements inside UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, view, calayer

I've got a UIWebView and I add a MKMapView as it's subview. The WebView contains buttons that should be over the MKMapView. I tried adding a mask to my MapView using CALayer, so there is a mask through which the buttons appear. But it doesn't work since buttons are visible but not clickable. Is there any way to bring the CALayer of the MapView underneath the CALayer of the buttons. But the Map should be draggable as well.

well I this is the code for creating a mask with the form of the defined picture;

CALayer* maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
  maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 180);
  maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange_check.png"] CGImage];

Thank you.

Comment: or how can I get a pointer to the buttons' layer or maybe applying zPozition

Comment: is there anyway of putting different UI elements in a layer? Or is there any way of creating "holes" inside my MKMapView?